# Eclipse for BlackBerry, set up the Eclipse envirorment

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

Hallo. I have problems by setting the Eclipse envirorment, can anybody provide me a useful step-by step instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is still not very smooth process. Check out this post, may be it will help:

http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/138210-setup-up-eclipse-blackberry-development.html

Answer (score 4):

RIM now has a full-featured Eclipse plug-in for BlackBerry development, and you should use it at this point.  The above answer links to an outdated guide that does not mention this plugin.

http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/devbetasoftware/javaplugin.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the following [RIM walkthrough](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/16874/index.html?name=Tutorial+-+BlackBerry+Java+Plug-in+for+Eclipse1.1&language=English&userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Java+Plug-in+for+Eclipse+%28Win%29&subCategory=)